# Correct Rest API endpoint

Tags: api, rest, endpoint, urn

Hi Im working on a REST API for a e-commerce app and had a couple questions about which are the correct URNs to map some specific actions, having in mind the definition of URI stated on RFC 3986: `A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a compact sequence of characters that identifies an abstract or physical resource.`

1. The action of sharing a post which receives an email and shares the post url via mail. Specific posts are mapped to /api/posts/id which is correct. The thing is I don't know how to map the URL of this action. A post to an URI like /api/posts/id/share is totally incorrect by definition of URI considering that share is an action and not a resource.
2. The action of resetting your password and the action of asking for a password reset email. Users are mapped to /api/users. Something like /api/users/password-reset-email and /api/users/password-reset would be incorrect following the same guideline explained before.

Answer (score 1):

The key takeaway from the dissertation that introduced REST is:

> Any information that can be named can be a resource...

Have a look at [Resources and Resource Identifiers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) for more information.

In other words, an action *is* a resource.
In your own words, a URI is a sequence of characters that identifies an "**abstract** or physical resource". Just because an action doesn't easily map to a tangible object doesn't make it less of a resource.

There are status codes which only exist to respond to 'actions' (e.g. [`202 Accepted`](https://www.webfx.com/web-development/glossary/http-status-codes/what-is-a-202-status-code/)).

All in all, `POST /api/posts/{id}/share` seems completely reasonable.

`POST` is really there as a 'catch all' for actions. In [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) it says the "function performed by the POST method is determined by the server" and the function performed "might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI".

The main points:

1. An 'action' should almost always involve `POST`
2. The 'action' performed should relate to the URI and body of the `POST` request.
3. You should return an appropriate status code (e.g. `200`, `201`, `202`, `204`, `4xx`).